# Set QWidget on top of current application but not other application

Tags: qt

I have an application with several windows.
Each window is a QWidget without parent.

I want those QWidget to be **on top** of the application, but not on top of **other application**.
It's like the windows in Visual Studio, for instance, when they are free. They can't be hidden by the main window, but can be by an other application.

I tried with ***"setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);"*** , but it keeps the QWidget on top of all the applications.

Comment: I don't have qt installed at the moment, so I can't help a lot, but have you tried Qt::Tool as flag?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. In Qt doc, it's written "If there is a parent, the tool window will always be kept on top of it. If there isn't a parent, you may consider using Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint as well". And mine haven't parent.

Comment: and is there a reason for having no parents, considering that they are widgets of a main application?

Comment: Yes, they can be outside the main window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [SetWindowModality](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop) instead of WindowStayOnTopHint, and both [modal modes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowModality-enum) (Qt::WindowModal and Qt::ApplicationModal) permit other applications to be on top of your modal window.

LE: You can read more about the difference between *ApplicationModal* and *WindowModal* in the QDialog's documentation page, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#details)

LE 2: The problem is that you don't set a parent, so to solve this set a parent for every child window (everything except your main window) and everything will work as you expected (the child windows will be on top of the parent, but won't be on top of any other application windows):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(&w);
    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("Show a non-modal window");
    layout->addWidget(btn);
    QWidget* mainWindow = &w;
    QObject::connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [mainWindow]()
        {
            QWidget* dlg = new QWidget(mainWindow);
            QVBoxLayout* dlgLayout = new QVBoxLayout(dlg);
            dlg->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
            QLabel* lbl = new QLabel("Non-modal window...", dlg);
            dlgLayout->addWidget(lbl);

            dlg->show();
        });
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The difference between *ApplicationModal* and *WindowModal* is almost what I want, except that my widgets are not modals :-( They are used to show some tools, like in photoshop for instance.

Comment: see the edit, you need to set the main-window as a parent for every other windows

Comment: Set the parent and add the option `setWindowFlags(Qt::Window)` seems to do the job. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be another problem : the widget cannot be painted outside its parent if it is set after being shown. To be more clear, I have a problem if I do this:
`QWidget* dlg = new QWidget(0);`
`dlg->show();`
`dlg->setParent(mainWindow);`

Comment: setParent resets the window flags, see the documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent
    so you hide the child widget, set the parent, set the window flag and after that show it again:
            dlg->hide();
            dlg->setParent(mainWindow);
            dlg->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
            dlg->show();

Comment: There is no need for the hide, Qt does that automatically.

Comment: I feel stupid, I didn't know that! Thank you very much, it works great.

Comment: This does not work for me. I use Qt5. When I test the code, the child window is not always on top of the main-window! I should, shouldn't it? I also want to build an application like photoshop (like Nagawica said) where I have a Tool-window always on top of the main window.

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux it seems to me you are you looking for mdi area, or i don't understand your problem? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#details

Comment: @Zlatomir It's almost, what I want, but what if I want to be able to move the subwindows out of the mainwindow area and still have the subwindows stay on top of the mainwindow, but not have them be modal. Is this possible with Qt?

Answer (score 0):

I've used and worked for Qt 5.3.0

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint| Qt::Window);
```

Qt::Tool can also be used instead of QWindow
Also set Parent before calling this. and it will work nicely

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

I have a non-modal QDialog that I want to stay in front of my app, but only my app.
Before showing the dialog I set the application's QMainWindow as its parent:

```
foreach( QWidget* p_widget, qApp->topLevelWidgets() )
{
    if ( QMainWindow* p_main_window = qobject_cast<QMainWindow*>( p_widget ) )
    {
        m_p_settings_dialog->setParent( p_main_window );
    }
}
```

Then I set the flags:

```
m_p_settings_dialog->setWindowFlags( Qt::Window
                                     | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint
                                     | Qt::WindowTitleHint
                                     | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint );
```

And then I show the dialog.

Now it works flawlessly for me. No need to set Qt::WindowStaysOnTopFlag at all.
Good luck!